# excel file read rows and columns - php

Tags: php, excel, csv, phpexcel

```
$arr=array();
$row = -1;
if (($handle = fopen("out.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        $row++;
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $arr[$row][$c]= $data[$c];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I'm using this code to read excel file data, this code counts elements in a row that are divided by comma (,),

Name, Surname, Num, Tel

1. Name
2. Surname
3. Num
4. tel

but in one field I have word **Orginal**, and this code also divides element by that word like this:

1. Orgina
2. l

and in that way, I receive wrong elemnts, any help?

Comment: Can you show the actual file you are trying to read with the content causing the problem so others can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Show the picture of this part of file, perhaps there's a problem inside this row, not in code.

Comment: BTW - you could replace the entire code in the loop with `$arr[] = $data;` if you just want to copy all of the array.

Comment: how i can upload a file

Comment: @NigelRen i updated description. I insert row how it looks in editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
```

the 1000 is the maximum length of data to read, as your data (in the example posted) has more than that, it will split the data.

To allow it to read the data properly you can just leave the second and third parameters as defaults ( null for length - in other words any length and the default  delimiter is a comma anyway...

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
```